# Telerik MVC Grid leaves empty fields after insert or cancel if custom popup editor is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

Telerik MVC Grid 2016.3.914 on asp.net core 1.0.0

When using custom popup edit like 
.Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Person"))

After adding new record grid adds new row but it is completely empty. Row is inserted in db and after grid is refreshed it appears normally. Also if you click add and then cancel (in popup window) grid will remain with new empty row.

Comment: My magic 8 ball isn't working, you should post your code and also what the console on your browser says the problem is, might be a while before I'm magically able to guess your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

This behaviour appeared then adding grouping to datasource like

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Group(groups => {groups.Add(p => p.LibraryAssetSubType); })

Removing group will make grid work normally
(after you click add button you have edit dialog popuped and a new empty line in grid behind it. After you click cancel dialog closes and new empty line disperses )

But once you add group dialog will leave empty line any time you click add and then cancel (also adding new line will leave new line empty before you refresh grid)